# Trying to make a picture's background fit with a background that the picture is on

Tags: website-design, background, blending

I have a picture on top of a background that is wider than it and the background colors don't match. I tried to use the eye drop but you can still tell it does not blend in. I was wondering if i can make both backgrounds blend in another way?

[image]

Comment: It would really help if you posted an example.  It would be even better if you could post your code.  If you are trying to do this in pure code it would serve better on StackOverflow.

Comment: Updated with a picture. Notice on the right it does not blend in with the picture on the left. Also i plan to do this all on Photoshop in terms of the image,i then will put it as code on a website.

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop:

Setup your document and place your image:

[image]

Click the `Rectangle Marquee Tool` and select the background from the image:

[image]

Go to `Edit -> Copy Merged` then go to `File -> New` and click <kbd>ok</kbd> then go to `Edit -> Paste`:

[image]

Take the file and save it out as `foobar.psd`.  Go to `Edit -> Define pattern`:

[image]

Create a new layer and place it below the layer with your image:

[image]

Click the `Paint Bucket Tool` with it defined as pattern and locate the pattern you created:

[image]

Convert the image layer to a rasterized layer.  After applying the pattern go to the `Clone Stamp Tool` and play around with the layers and background and take your time on this:

[image]

Ideally I would add the text with HTML and CSS but thats me.  This is a quick way to do it especially if you are trying to knock out a lot of main image galleries for a store website.  There are other ways but based on your situation I would do it this way since you can massage the background color better.

Comment: I tried to rasterize the layer but it is grayed out.

Comment: This seems like a very complicated method

Comment: Its what im used to when a client supplies a square image and they want to use it for a marketing slider.  As stated it depends on the image.

Answer (score 4):

### Result:

[image]

*Notice how the sharp division between the background and the floor has remained without a repetitive look.*

### Steps:

**Make a rectangle selection between the downbell and the beginning of the area you want to delete.**

[image]

**Go to `Edit > Content-Aware Scale`.**

[image]

**Resize the selection.**

[image]